# Text characteristics identifier

Tags: text, fonts, colors, size

I need an app where I can just copy a block of text and have it identify the typeface, color, size, etc. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery `css()` function would be great for this. You would just need to build a function that checks for the CSS properties you are looking for and return them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var test = $('p').css('font-family');

alert(test);

});
```

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/ecedo[link text](http://jsbin.com/ecedo)

Here is documentation on the JQuery CSS function: 
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I should have asked, are you looking for a desktop app or are you building a web app?